# Set translated field

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I'm having some trouble finding how to handle field translations in the documentation.

I have a requirement to keep certain fields in English and Japanese. I periodically have to update nodes and taxonomy terms programmatically. I'm doing this with a combination of EntityQuery and the Entity class.

Is there a set function that takes a language code? For example;

```
$term->set('field_my_field', 'my value', 'ja');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You update another translation by getting an object for that language, and then you set the values of those fields.

```
$translation->set('field_my_field', 'my en value');
$translation = $term->getTranslation('ja');
$translation->set('field_my_field', 'my ja value');
$translation->save();
```

Those translation objects are actually shallow clones that have a different internal active language code, so you can update multiple translations and then save, for example.